# Redirect to different URL outside project from Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can i redirect to different url eg: yahoo.com,hotmail.com  from my controller i am using Spring 3.0 and using config and not annotations.

one thing i forgot to mention is the url will be user input so cannot add it in the config

Thanks
Gauls

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequest;

    String redirectUrl = null; 
            SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest)request.getSession().getAttribute(DefaultSavedRequest.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
            if(savedRequest != null) {
                redirectUrl = "redirect:" + savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
            } else {             }      }
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use redirect: prefix  in the controller method.

```
public String method(){
   return "redirect:http://yahoo.com"
}
```

More info in the section 13.5.3.2 of the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Woudn't using this `response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);` in your controller suffice?

Comment: Then, wouldn't JavaScript help in that case? Get the input and use window.location.href = userURL; In case, you're storing it in ur DB.. u can always write it onto the page and use it however you want to. (How? There's numerous ways. depends totally on you)