# Spring mvc redirect to a page from formBackingObject()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 2.5. I want to redirect to a url from

`formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)` method used in a spring controller.

As there is no ModelAndView object in this method; also I created response object bur it did not work as well.

```
HttpServletResponse response = null;
response.sendRedirect("google.com");
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formBackingObject() will run complete and will not redirect. In controller handleRequest() method can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override HandleRequest method.
Sample code:

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {

    if (condition) {
        return new ModelAndView("downloadInProgress");
    }else{
        return super.handleRequest(request,response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In yr controller do this:

```
public String method(){
     return "redirect:http://google.com"
}
```

Also asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224592/redirect-to-different-url-outside-project-from-controller/4224689#4224689) btw.